# Network error when making a GET request in React using Axios

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I'm developing a React web application and I'm trying to make a GET request to an API using Axios. However, I'm getting a network error and I can't figure out what the issue is.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:5198/api",
    withCredentials: false,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',   
  }
})

api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  if (token) {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
  return config;
});

export default api;
```

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import api from '../axios';

export const GetData = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await api.get('/devices');
        setData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    getData();
  }, []);
 
  return (
    getData()
  )
}

export default GetData;
```

When I run this code, I get the following error in the browser console:
GET http://localhost:5198/api/devices net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)

What could be causing this network error? I have checked the URL and the port, and they seem to be correctly set. Is there anything else I can check or any possible solutions to fix this issue?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have CORS setup on the server running at `http://localhost:5198/api`? If not it may be worth looking at [this stackoverflow answer about CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765/13121213)

Comment: Yes, I have configured CORS at http://localhost:5198/api, but it does not work. I am using ASP.NET Core